# Why doesn't std::function work in this situation?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, stl, most-vexing-parse

Imagine I have a type:

```
struct my_type
{
    double operator()(int a)
    {
        return 3.1415;
    }
};
```

Then I'd like to wrap it in `std::function`. Consider two different approaches:

```
my_type m_t;
std::function<double(int)> f(std::move(m_t));
std::cout << f(4) << std::endl;
```

Everything works nice as I expected, first digits of *PI* are printed. Then the second approach:

```
std::function<double(int)> ff(my_type()); 
std::cout << ff(4) << std::endl;
```

It seems to me, that this code is **absolutely** the same as the first one. `rvalue` is passed as an argument for `function` wrapper. But the problem is, that the second code doesn't compile! I have really no idea why so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the famous [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue. For `std::function<double(int)> ff(my_type());`, you're not declaraing an object of type `std::function<double(int)>` as you expected, but a function named `ff`, which returns an object of type `std::function<double(int)>` and has a single (unnamed) parameter which is a pointer to function returning type `my_type` and taking no input.

To fix the issue you could add additional parentheses or use braces which was supported from C++11 (braces could be used for disambiguity because it can't be used for parameter list). e.g.

```
std::function<double(int)> ff1((my_type())); 
std::function<double(int)> ff2(my_type{}); 
std::function<double(int)> ff3{my_type()}; 
std::function<double(int)> ff4{my_type{}};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YMOQ69744)